# Synchronising GEF editor with EMF model with two EMF adapters

Tags: multithreading, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef, synchronization

I'm having trouble synchronising my GEF editor with the EMF-based model. I think this is due to the fact that the model-internal EMF Adapter, or rather the methods it calls, aren't finished before the editor's Adapter's `notifyChanged()` is called and updates the model children. This leads to the editor view being out-of-sync with the model itself, or rather, the changes to the model not being represented in the view when they should be.

Consider this set up. A `Command` "`CreateNodeCommand`" adds a node to the underlying model:

```java
@Override
public void execute() {
...
getNewNode().setGraph(getGraph());
...
}
```

The `GraphEditPart` has an internal class extending `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Adapter`. It's `notifyChanged()` method is indeed notified, as tested similar to below (incomplete code):

```java
@Override
public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
  switch (notification.getEventType()) {
case Notification.ADD:
      System.err.println("ADD occurred!");
  refreshChildren();
}
```

The problem is, that the (third-party) model itself also implements an `Adapter`, which in turn runs a number of methods on the new model element, such as adding an ID, etc.

It seems to me that the fact that the new element's figure doesn't show up in the editor directly after it's been created - but only after the next editing step, the figure for which then doesn't appear - suggests that the *model* adapter is still busy setting up the new element while `refreshChildren()` is already being called by the *editor* adapter.

This seems to call for **synchronisation**, but I'm unsure whether this can be achieved with built-in Java functionality for multithreading, or calls for an EMF-based approach.

Please share your knowledge about synchronising in EMF.

Many thanks in advance!

## EDIT

On request, here is the source code for the `getModelChildren()` method:

```java
@Override 
protected List<EObject> getModelChildren() {
  List<EObject> allModelObjects = new ArrayList<EObject>();
  allModelObjects.addAll(((MyGraph) getModel()).getTokens());
  allModelObjects.addAll(((MyGraph) getModel()).getNodes());
  return allModelObjects;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the model? I was unable to understand if you have one model or two.

Comment: @vainolo: It's *one* model, an EMF-based (fairly) generic graph model. This model implements `Adapter` to listen to changes within itself. My problem seems to be that the `Adapter` I use in my editor is notified before the actions triggered from the model-internal `Adapter` have finished, hence the element seems to have been created, but is (I guess) not yet added "model-internally" to the list I use for `getChildren()`.

Comment: I'm no EMF wizard,  but it seems strange to me that you get notified before the change is finished.  Maybe you are being notified of another change?

Comment: @vainolo: Yes, I thought it'd be strange. But it *is* the `ADD` notification. At least I get the standard out's message. I guess the model method must add the element first, then modify it (?) as needed, then add it to the list of elements that `getModelChildren()` calls.

Comment: Can you post the code of `getModelChildren`? If the model is generated from EMF then there is no way that the children are not in the model when you are notified.

Comment: @vainolo: Thanks, I've added the code in the question. Could it possibly have something to do with the method being protected?

Comment: Strange... Everything looks OK. Do you know if the code for `setGraph` was modified from the generated code? I read the generated code I have using EMF and notifications are only given AFTER all the changes are done to the model. I think you are going to need a very long debug session to understand what is going on :-(

Comment: @vainolo: Turns out there wouldn't be any way anyone could help me with this, cf. my answer. D'uh! So the model devs kindly moved that one line for me, and now it works :).

Comment: Was this done on purpose? do they know why? because if not, maybe something else will break

Comment: @vainolo: This wasn't done on purpose. I guess the modded the generated code, and simply added logic after the call. They've never envisaged the model to be used in a GEF/other graphical application, so I guess they just didn't heed any problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging the (3rd party) model, I found out that the `Graph`'s `enotify()` fired the notification before the actual adding took place, hence my `Adapter`received the notification too early, i.e., before the node had been added.

The notification is now called after the add and everything works fine.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try extending EContentAdapter instead of AdapterImpl, and not forget to call

```
super.notifyChanged(Notification notification);
```

in it. It's an adapter, which will add itself to new elements of the model, and notify you then they are changed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try `EContentAdapter`.

Comment: `EContentAdapter` works fine, but doesn't fix the issue. It seems that this really *is* a sync issue.